# How to create a custom Spring PropertySource that depends on a Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm attempting to use the spring-cloud stack for a project that would use Zuul.  In my organization we have a custom configuration stack that is xml-based and does property composition and hierarchical overrides.  Because of the way this configuration is handled, I've struggled to create a PropertySource for it.

My custom PropertySource must use my Config bean, but because the PropertySources are initialized during the bootstrapping of spring boot, the application context is not fully initialized yet and I can't get to my custom Bean that exposes our xml-based configuration system.

@ConfigurationProperties appears to be entirely biased toward .properties and .yaml files.  The Config bean is initialized in an ApplicationContextInitializer.  Is there a way to delay the resolution of the ConfigurationProperties within the various services so I can construct my custom property source using my Config bean after it is initialized?

Comment: [spring-cloud-consul-config][1] uses the spring cloud config bootstrap mechanism, so that the normal application context has the values.


  [1]: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/tree/master/spring-cloud-consul-config

Comment: Thank you Spencer.  That is a helpful link that gives a concrete demonstration of what is mentioned in the official documentation linked by Mr. Syer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I originally attempted (well before asking the question) to create a custom PropertySourceLocator in my config (as mentioned by Dave Syer and well documented in the link he gave) and register it with my own spring.factories (Again, demonstrated in the helpful link given by Spencer Gibb in the comment.)  The problem is that my property source needs to be configured after some work that is done in an ApplicationContextInitializer and the property sources all seem to be resolved before that occurs (at least those wired in as a factory for org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration).  I guess I hinted at this by stating that I needed a particular bean in my PropertySource that I couldn't get from the ApplicationContext at the time.

Anyway, to get around that, I am now registering the property source in an **PriorityOrdered** **ApplicationContextInitializer** to take place after another one that initializes my config object.  Something like: `context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(myPropertySource);`

This seems to get my property source into the environment at the correct time and allows me to perform customization of the context before hand as needed.

Comment: What do you mean by PriorityOrdered? Is that some kind of annotation that makes sure it gets run first? Otherwise, how do you get it to run first? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In Spring Cloud you would need to register some `BootstrapConfiguration` (per the user guide: http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources) that has a `PropertySourceLocator` bean. It shouldn't be any harder than that.

P.S. `@ConfigurationProperties` is not biased toward .properties and .yaml files - it binds to the `Environment` which knows nothing about file formats.

Comment: Point taken on the ConfigurationProperties not biased toward .properties and .yaml files.  It seems in the configuration that any sort of overriding is expected to be done that way.  Where I ran into trouble was that I was implementing PropertySource instead of EnumerablePropertySource (found through Spencer's link) so it was having trouble mapping my custom properties correctly.  Sadly I didn't find any great documentation on what should be returned from getProperty in PropertySource and Object isn't really intuitive.  Yes, I know I just sound confused...